# AlertDialog doesn't want to be displayed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have good working code when I asked the user to delete item ot not.

```
case R.id.item_Delete:
        Log.d("TAG","Deletion ...");
        AlertDialog.Builder delAllDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        delAllDialog.setTitle("Confirm deletion");
        TextView dialogTxt_id = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams dialogTxt_idLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogTxt_id.setLayoutParams(dialogTxt_idLayoutParams);
        dialogTxt_id.setText("Delete?");
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(dialogTxt_id); 
        delAllDialog.setView(layout);
        delAllDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                delete();
            }
        });
        break; 
...
```

It works great!
I just **copy** this peace of code and place it to another similar activity in right the same menu code.
And I have got `Deletion..` in my log and then **nothing happened**. LogCat it clear, no errors.

I search and find several other same questions (for example [Android - AlertDialog doesn't show when called from Main-Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444064/android-alertdialog-doesnt-show-when-called-from-main-method) ) but nor cleaning the project nor other things doesn't solve my problem..
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no delAllDialog.show() in the code you posted. That could the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
 delAllDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `delAllDialog.show()` to display your  alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

@Foenix, try replacing `this` with  `YourActivityName.this`

e.g.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SampleActivity.this);
```